Permanova - adonis2
I have richness (ecology) data for 9 plots. There are three lines, each consisting of three plots. In the first two rows, I have wealth data over 5 years. On the third line, just 3 years. I would like to check the effect of time, that is, if there are significant differences in wealth over the years and the effect of the plots (distributed systematically within the lines). Finally, the effect of the lines and all the interactions. I used the following code:
data$Wealth\[is.na(data$Wealth)\] \<- mean(data$Wealth, na.rm = TRUE)

permanova_resultado \<- adonis2(data$Wealth \~ Line + Installment + Year +

Line\*Parcel + Line\*Year + Year\*Parcel, date = data,

permutations = 1000, strata = Line)

print(permanova_resultado)

I managed to run it, however, now I have the following error:

Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) :

contrasts can only be applied to factors with 2 or more levels
Can you help me?
Next, should I apply t-test? If there is a significant effect of any of the factors?
#permanova only for line and installments
aqui estão os dados
dados <- read.table(text = "
Linha Parcela Ano Riqueza
1 1 a1 8
1 1 a2 8
1 1 a3 12
1 1 a4 12
1 1 a5 12
1 2 a1 12
1 2 a2 12
1 2 a3 13
1 2 a4 13
1 2 a5 13
1 3 a1 8
1 3 a2 7
1 3 a3 9
1 3 a4 9
1 3 a5 9
2 1 a1 12
2 1 a2 12
2 1 a3 11
2 1 a4 17
2 1 a5 16
2 2 a1 13
2 2 a2 13
2 2 a3 13
2 2 a4 13
2 2 a5 12
2 3 a1 8
2 3 a2 7
2 3 a3 6
2 3 a4 10
2 3 a5 10
3 1 a1 13
3 1 a2 12
3 1 a3 11
3 1 a4 NA
3 1 a5 NA
3 2 a1 11
3 2 a2 11
3 2 a3 9
3 2 a4 NA
3 2 a5 NA
3 3 a1 9
3 3 a2 9
3 3 a3 9
3 3 a4 NA
3 3 a5 NA
", header = TRUE)




header 1
header 2




cell 1
cell 2


cell 3
cell 4






header 1
header 2




cell 1
cell 2


cell 3
cell 4






header 1
header 2





cell 2


cell 3
cell 4



riq_parc\<-adonis2(data$Riqueza \~ Parcel, data = data, permutations = 1000, strata = data$Line)

print(riq_parc)

#average test - installment

Parcel \<- factor(data$Parcel, labels = data$Parcel\[1:3\])

pairwise.t.test(data$Wealth, data$Parcel)

I tried using the code above and also using the easynova package for unbalanced samples. However, the result showed that the model is perfect. There are no differences, so I tried using the adonis2 function from the vegan package

I'm not sure that adonis2 is the right function for your data. The help page says that "The left-hand side (LHS) of the formula must be either a community data matrix or a dissimilarity matrix," whereas you have species richness.

Your model using easynova was probably a perfect fit because it included all possible interaction terms, and you only have one replicate for each unique combination of Line, Parcel, and Year. You'll have the same problem regardless of the package you use as long as you include all interaction terms. You'll need to remove any interactions or predictors that you're not interested in the effects of, instead. I don't know your study design, but if you're just interested in time and using the nine plots as replicates, you could just include time as an effect.

I'm also wondering if a GLM with time as a continuous variable might make more sense than PERMANOVA?
